# Find the difference between two Django datetimes

Tags: django, datetime, templatetag

I have a template tag as follows,

```
     @register.filter
def get_runtime(date_start=None, date_end=None):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
    if date_start and date_end is not None:
        date_start = datetime.strptime(date_start, fmt)
        date_end = datetime.strptime(date_end, fmt)
        return date_end - date_start
    else:
        return None
```

and I am passing it into one of my website as follows,

```
<b>Run Time (min): </b> {{ value.date_start|get_runtime:value.date_end }}<br>
```

But it showing an error "strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is a type of `value`? is it model and `date_start`, `date_end` are DateTimeField?

Comment: That code could not give that error. Although you have an error in your `if` logic (it should be `if date_start is not None and date_end is not None`), you still wouldn't get that error if one of them was None - you would get "TypeError: must be str, not None".

Comment: @sneawo: Yeah its datetime in database table

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is a model and `date_start`, `date_end` are DateTimeFields, then it's easier to add a method to model

```
def runtime(self):
    if self.date_start and self.date_end:
        return self.date_end - self.date_start
```

and use it in template:

```
{{ value.runtime }}
```

For your solution it's better use a tag instead of filter, because you do not modify value and calculate something else. Function returns `None` by default. So it will look like:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_runtime(date_start, date_end):
    if date_start and date_end:
        return date_end - date_start
```

in template:

```
{% get_runtime value.date_start value.date_end %}
```